# Instructional video creation: "see-through glass" whiteboard effect

Tags: effects

How is this effect achieved?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNiLz.jpg

(Original video:

)

Answer (score 2):

The instructor is just standing behind glass and writing on it.

Comment: My handwriting isn't that neat when I'm in front of the writing surface, but, yeah, those look to be real dry erase markers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If that was the case, then the writing should appear in reverse to us. So that's not what's happening.

Comment: Or the instructor is writing in reverse, so it would look ok to us